# Open in new tab after ajax response in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

Open in new tab after ajax response in javascript is not working,

tried with _newtab and _blank

But none of them is working,

I say,

Is there any solution to get the answer ?

Comment: Is there any change to get the code you're working on?

Comment: Without further information like code-sniplets, which browser/os you're working on and what exactly isn't working a expected, no one'll be able to provide any help...

Comment: I'm using the window.open method after ajax call in javascript

Answer (score 5):

From JavaScript, you **cannot** open new tabs. You can only open new windows. It's up to the user's browser settings how it opens new windows (be it in a new tab, a new tab in the background, or a new window).

JavaScript *does not* and *cannot* even know if your browser supports tab. And it does not have access to anything on the outsides of the browser (unless there's leverage from an extension I suppose).

And as a reminder, there *are* browsers with no tabs, and others with no windows even. Tabs are just browser features, and never part of any language specification.

Comment: So i can't open a page after ajax response in javascript ?

Ok is there any solution in jQuery ?

Comment: @ManiM you *can* open a new window or redirect to a url. You just *can't* open a tab specifically, since JavaScript has no business with tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Use this -> `window.open(YourUrlInsertHere, '_blank');`

Answer (score 0):

use window.open() method. For more details [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)

Comment: I'm using window.open() method only, it's called after the http response, So it's opens as pop up :(

Comment: I think this might be the only option you have as new tabs cannot be opened programmatically :)

Comment: Is there any other solutions ?

Comment: Most browsers open tabs instead of new window on window.open() but the behavior is configurable. There's no guarantee that a new tab will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Above given answer is great to help but in some way, they are not complete working solution and I came here for finding the same solution and will like to add the working example of it.

```
var win = window.open('_link is here_', 'name');
if (win) {
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
} else {
    //Browser has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

'*name*' is a name of the window. Following names are supported

- _blank - URL is loaded into a **new tab**. *This is default.*
- _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- _self - URL replaces the current page
- _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded

Depending on the browser's implementation this will work.
There is nothing you can do to make it open in a window rather than a tab.

Also find the sample example of it [here](http://www.tutsplanet.com/open-url-new-tab-using-javascript-196/)